# Discord.py: How can I make a command that i can only do with my user ID?

Tags: discord.py

So I want to use a command that only I can do and link it so I can us my User Id, like

`@commands.has_any_role()`

But with my user ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to check your own id, and use an if statement to check the user's id:

it's been quite a while since I've done discord.py, but here's my crack at it:

```py
# Set your id here
my_id = 1234567890

async def my_command(ctx):
  if ctx.author.id == my_id:
    // do something
```

To create your custom decorator for multiple commands, just define it:

```py
# Set your id here
my_id = 1234567890

is_me = commands.check(lambda ctx: ctx.author.id == my_id)

@commands.command()
@is_me
async def command():
  // do something
```

The benefit of having a custom decorator is that it reduces the indentation required AND can apply to multiple functions.

Comment: @LightingWave6 
I've added another solution for multiple commands